# Document Generation with template in Enterprise Architect with an Add-In C#

Tags: c#, add-in, enterprise-architect, documentation-generation

I am working on an Enterprise Architect Add-In in C# in Visual Studio Express 2013 to make documentations for a single element/elements in a package. I made a template in EA with the help of the Document Generator, where i want to write some of the element's properties on the output. Example:

```
package >
element >
Name: {Element.Name}... more attributes of the element
< element
< package
```

The problem is that when i use my Add-In to generate the document the output will be like this:

package >

Name: Random TestName

< package

between package > < package is blank, and as default the document should not contain these fields in the output, how can i make it disappear? I tried to fill between the package fields with something like {Pkg.Version}, but i only get this text in the output, not the value of it. In the Document Template Designer under Sections window if i check "Element" box it checks the "Package" box too, but if i try to uncheck the "Package" it unchecks the "Element" too - any suggestions how can i make it work?
My Add-In works like this:

```
EA.Element element = repository.GetTreeSelectedObject();
int elementID = element.ElementID;
EA.DocumentGenerator docGen = repository.CreateDocumentGenerator();
docGen.NewDocument("");
docGen.InsertTemplate("RandomTemp");
docGen.DocumentElement(elementID, 2, "RandomTemp"); // gets the element by ID
docGen.SaveDocument("DOCUMENT.pdf", EA.DocumentType.dtPDF);
```

+: that would work for me either if i can reach somehow the package properties of the element too.

Thanks in advance.

Tamas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`docGen.insertTemplate` prints out your template as is, without filling in the fields. Remove that line of code and it should be fine

The document will generate the report following your template just fine with the following line of code you put: `docGen.DocumentElement(elementID, 2, "RandomTemp");`

Comment: Thanks a lot! Do you know if i can somehow print several elements (like from a package) with two different templates? I tried with docGen.DocumentElement(elementID, 2, "RandomTemp"); then from the second element i am trying to use the other template
docGen.DocumentElement(elementID, 2, "RandomTempSecond");
, but still uses the first.
Note: I got my pdf with all the documentation i need, i just try to use another template from the second element to document not the spam the Package name/logo, etc.

Comment: @TamasKiss it should work, make sure you put down the template name correctly

Comment: I encountered another problem: If i am trying to document a rootpackage in EA with a template it is not working, only with any subpackage - can anyone help me with this?